# Tkhtml with python 3.5

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I was searching for Tkinter widget for displaying webpage/Url/ads in my Tkinter window widget.and after some google/stack search, I found a widget called ([tk_html_widget](https://pypi.org/project/tk-html-widgets/)) and [this page](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/HTML+widgets) where I found Tkhtml...but I don't know how to use both(tk_html_widgets and Tkhtml). Please refer me something for study these(tk_html_widgets and Tkhtml)

Thank you

Comment: getting tk toolkits that don't ship with your python distribution to work is not for the faint hearted, however in this case someone has packages up a python wrapper and the tk binaries needed: https://bitbucket.org/aivarannamaa/tkinterhtml they say they have tested it on python 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, but I cannot speak as to how well it works. as it is on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/tkinterhtml/ you should be able to `pip install tkinterhtml`

Comment: @JamesKentI agreed with you I wrote the program in tkinterhtml but its only support text I need something that supports "URLs/google ads", even its don't supports "<a>" tag

Comment: I can help you add url/hyperlink like behaviour to a normal text widget, but I can't help you with Google ads, that's more than likely a massive endeavour involving js, css and iframes

Comment: ok I tried "ifram" but it's not working

Comment: I've posted an example of hyperlink type behaviour in a text widget as an answer, but I cannot help you with anything further

Comment: @JamesKent thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for an example of hyperlink type behaviour:

```
__all__ = ["LinkScrolledText"]

try:
    from tkinter import scrolledtext
except ImportError:
    import ScrolledText as scrolledtext

class HyperlinkManager(object):
    """A class to easily add clickable hyperlinks to Text areas.
    Usage:
      callback = lambda : webbrowser.open("http://www.google.com/")
      text = tk.Text(...)
      hyperman = tkHyperlinkManager.HyperlinkManager(text)
      text.insert(tk.INSERT, "click me", hyperman.add(callback))
    From http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-text-hyperlink.htm
    """
    def __init__(self, text, statusfunc=None):
        self.text = text
        self.statusfunc = statusfunc
        self.text.tag_config("hyper", foreground="blue", underline=1)
        self.text.tag_bind("hyper", "<Enter>", self._enter)
        self.text.tag_bind("hyper", "<Leave>", self._leave)
        self.text.tag_bind("hyper", "<Button-1>", self._click)
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.links = {}

    def add(self, action, tooltip=None):
        """Adds an action to the manager.
        :param action: A func to call.
        :return: A clickable tag to use in the text widget.
        """
        tag = "hyper-%d" % len(self.links)
        self.links[tag] = [action, tooltip]
        return ("hyper", tag)

    def _enter(self, event):
        self.text.config(cursor="hand2")
        for tag in self.text.tag_names(tk.CURRENT):
            if (tag[:6] == "hyper-"):
                tooltip = self.links[tag][1]
                if self.statusfunc:
                    self.statusfunc(tooltip) # don't care if no tooltip as function clears if it doesn't
                return

    def _leave(self, event):
        self.text.config(cursor="")
        if self.statusfunc:
            self.statusfunc()

    def _click(self, event):
        for tag in self.text.tag_names(tk.CURRENT):
            if (tag[:6] == "hyper-"):
                func = self.links[tag][0]
                if func:
                    func()
                return

class LinkScrolledText(scrolledtext.ScrolledText):
    """A class to add hyperlink functionality to a scrolledtext widget
    the link does not actually have to be an actual hyperlink,
    just a callable action.
    an optional tooltip can be provided that will be displayed in the bottom left
    just like a url would be in a browser when hovering over a link.
    """
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        scrolledtext.ScrolledText.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.status = tk.Label(self)
        self._hyper = HyperlinkManager(self, self._showstatus)
        self.reset_links()

    def _showstatus(self, status=None):
        if status:
            self.status.configure(text=status)
            self.status.place(relx=0, rely=1, anchor='sw')
        else:
            self.status.place_forget()

    def reset_links(self):
        self._hyper.reset()

    def insert_hyperlink(self, position, text, action, tag=None, tooltip=None):
        tags = self._hyper.add(action, tooltip)
        if type(tag) == list:
            tags = tags + tag
        elif tag != None:
            tags.append(tag)
        self.insert(position, text, tags)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        import tkinter as tk
    except ImportError:
        import Tkinter as tk
    root = tk.Tk()
    tb = LinkScrolledText(root)
    tb.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    tb.insert_hyperlink("end", "Test", action=None, tooltip="This is a test")
    root.mainloop()
```